# Intellij gives incompatible kotlin version but no kotlin is used

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-serenity

I'm trying to upgrade my cucumber/serenity project but sadly this breaks more then fixes one of the issues is when I want to run a seperate feature file I get the message from intellij

```
Error:Kotlin: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.13.
```

But as far as I know and see I never use kotlin. It's a maven project also with following pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.nbb.cph</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-serenity</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>cph-serenity</name>
    <description>Hive Selenium testing</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>2.6.0</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.6.0</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>2.6.0</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <tags></tags>
        <webdriver.base.url></webdriver.base.url>


  <!--      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>2.1.5</serenity.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.50</serenity.cucumber.version>-->

        <webdriver.driver>chrome</webdriver.driver>
        <webdriver.remote.driver>chrome</webdriver.remote.driver>

        <serenity.dry.run>false</serenity.dry.run>
        <hive.env>local</hive.env>

        <cucumber.runner>**/cucumber/CucumberTestSuite.java</cucumber.runner>
        <serenity.browser.height>1024</serenity.browser.height>
        <serenity.browser.width>1400</serenity.browser.width>
    </properties>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dryrun</id>
            <properties>
                <serenity.dry.run>true</serenity.dry.run>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>env:local</id>
            <properties>
                <hive.env>local</hive.env>
                <injected.tags>env:local</injected.tags>
                <cucumber.runner>**/cucumber/CucumberTestSuite.java</cucumber.runner>
                <serenity.project.name>NBB Hive Automated Testing @uat
                </serenity.project.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>


        <profile>
            <id>env:dev</id>
               <properties>
                <hive.env>dev</hive.env>
                <injected.tags>env:dev</injected.tags>
                <cucumber.runner>**/cucumber/CucumberTestSuite.java</cucumber.runner>
                <serenity.project.name>NBB Hive Automated Testing @dev
                </serenity.project.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>env:uat</id>
            <properties>
                <hive.env>uat</hive.env>
                <injected.tags>env:uat</injected.tags>
                <cucumber.runner>**/cucumber/CucumberTestSuite.java</cucumber.runner>
                <serenity.project.name>NBB Hive Automated Testing @uat
                </serenity.project.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>env:prd</id>
            <properties>
                <hive.env>prd</hive.env>
                <injected.tags>env:prd</injected.tags>
                <cucumber.runner>**/cucumber/CucumberTestSuite.java</cucumber.runner>
                <serenity.project.name>NBB Hive Automated Testing @prd
                </serenity.project.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>


        <profile>
            <id>target:desktop</id>
            <properties>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>target:mobile</id>
            <properties>
                <serenity.browser.height>1024</serenity.browser.height>
                <serenity.browser.width>700</serenity.browser.width>
            </properties>
        </profile>


        <profile>
            <id>grid:nbb-dev</id>
            <properties>
                <webdriver.remote.url>http://swvnchseld01.nbb.local:4444/wd/hub</webdriver.remote.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>grid:nbb-prd</id>
            <properties>
                <webdriver.remote.url>http://swvnchselp01.nbb.local:4444/wd/hub</webdriver.remote.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>grid:local</id>
            <properties>
                <webdriver.remote.url>http://localhost:4444/wd/hub</webdriver.remote.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>grid:none</id>
            <properties>
            </properties>
        </profile>


        <profile>
            <id>browser:edge</id>
            <properties>
                <hive.browser>edge</hive.browser>
                <injected.tags>browser:edge</injected.tags>
                <webdriver.remote.driver>edge</webdriver.remote.driver>
            </properties>

        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>browser:firefox</id>
            <properties>
                <hive.browser>firefox</hive.browser>
                <injected.tags>browser:firefox</injected.tags>
                <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
                <webdriver.remote.driver>firefox</webdriver.remote.driver>
            </properties>

        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>browser:chrome</id>
            <properties>
                <hive.browser>chrome</hive.browser>
                <injected.tags>browser:chrome</injected.tags>
                <webdriver.driver>chrome</webdriver.driver>
                <webdriver.remote.driver>chrome</webdriver.remote.driver>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber6</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-ensure</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- plugins -->
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <password>${hive_test_account_1_password}</password>
                        <password>${hive_test_account_2_password}</password>
                        <password>${hive_test_account_3_password}</password>
                        <password>${hive_test_account_4_password}</password>
                        <password>${hive_test_account_5_password}</password>
                        <password>${hive_test_account_6_password}</password>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                        <include>**/When*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.base.url>${webdriver.base.url}</webdriver.base.url>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
        <!--            <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>-->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${hive.env}/${hive.browser}/${current.time}
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>current-time</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>current.time</name>
                            <pattern>yyyyMMdd_HHmmss</pattern>
                            <timeZone>CET</timeZone>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Does anybody know what's going wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: Try to disable/enable/update Kotlin plugin bundled with IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: thank you that actually did it, disabling it